# Print from different class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I'm going over the basics for Python, and I got two functions to to work. A brute force and a dictionary method of solving problem 2 on leet code. I'm trying to make it work while using classes, however. I've tried making it one big class, and now I've split it into two classes. I'm not sure how to print the result from each function. Please help!

```
class Solution1:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # Complexity: O(n^2), very inefficient, especially as the list gets longer
    def twoSum_BF(self, nums, target):
        # don't want to look at the last index (i = index)
        for i in range(len(nums) - 1):
            # don't need to look at indices we've already seen
            # -> i + 1, then go to end of nums
            for j in range(i + 1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i] + nums[j] == target:
                    return [i, j]


# dict method
class Solution2:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # Complexity is O(n)?
    def twoSum_Dict(self, nums, target):
        seen = {}

        # enumerate gives both index and val at same time
        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            # check whether dict seen contains num
            # needed to add to curr to = target
            # we need tar - curr
            if target - num in seen:
                return [seen[target - num], i]
            elif num not in seen:
                seen[num] = i


x = [2, 7, 11, 15]
y = 9
print("The brute force method returns: ")
BF = (Solution1(x, y))
print(BF)

print("The dictionary method returns: ")
Dict = (Solution2(x, y))
print(Dict)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow! I mean no offense by this, but there's a lot of small errors here to really make a succinct answer to your question. I highly recommend taking a look at some `class` tutorials to try and get an understanding of how to use them. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp for a high level overview, and read the official docs to get some more flavor on exactly what's going on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html . I wish you the best of luck :)

Comment: you have to run these function. `BF.twoSum_BF(x, y)`, `Dict.twoSum_Dict(x, y)` to get results. And if you send `x, y` to `__init__` then in these functions you should use `self.x`, `self.y` without getting parameters `nums, target`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run functions to get results.

```
print( BF.twoSum_BF(x, y) )
print( Dict.twoSum_Dict(x, y) )
```

---

If you send `x,y` to `__init__` then you could use `self.x`, `self.y` in these functions instead of `num, target` and run without parameters `num, target`

```
print( BF.twoSum_BF() )
print( Dict.twoSum_Dict() )
```

Full code:

```
class Solution1:

    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target

    # Complexity: O(n^2), very inefficient, especially as the list gets longer
    def twoSum_BF(self):
        # don't want to look at the last index (i = index)
        for i in range(len(self.nums) - 1):
            # don't need to look at indices we've already seen
            # -> i + 1, then go to end of nums
            for j in range(i + 1, len(self.nums)):
                if self.nums[i] + self.nums[j] == self.target:
                    return [i, j]


class Solution2:

    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target

    # Complexity is O(n)?
    def twoSum_Dict(self):
        seen = {}

        # enumerate gives both index and val at same time
        for i, num in enumerate(self.nums):
            # check whether dict seen contains num
            # needed to add to curr to = target
            # we need tar - curr
            if self.target - num in seen:
                return [seen[self.target - num], i]
            elif num not in seen:
                seen[num] = i

x = [2, 7, 11, 15]
y = 9

print("The brute force method returns: ")
BF = Solution1(x, y)
print( BF.twoSum_BF() )

print("The dictionary method returns: ")
Dict = Solution2(x, y)
print( Dict.twoSum_Dict() )
```

Comment: this makes so much sense thank you so much!!!